# Android : Sometimes Google Map showing wrong current location

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, react-native-maps

I am using react-native-maps to show the map

I am getting my current location as follows:

```
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {

        region = {
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          latitudeDelta: this.state.position.latitudeDelta,
          longitudeDelta: this.state.position.longitudeDelta
        }

        this.setState(
          {
            position: {
              latitude: region.latitude,
              longitude: region.longitude,
              latitudeDelta: region.latitudeDelta,
              longitudeDelta: region.longitudeDelta,
              error: null
            }
          })
})
```

But some times it showing the before location that I am in
Can any one suggest how to solve this by code
Thank you

Comment: you need to stop gps and start again

Comment: yes I did that but no result

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using the parameter 'maximumAge'. e.g.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
      region: {
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude,
        latitudeDelta: this.state.position.latitudeDelta,
        longitudeDelta: this.state.position.longitudeDelta
      }
     this.setState(
      {
        position: {
          latitude: region.latitude,
          longitude: region.longitude,
          latitudeDelta: region.latitudeDelta,
          longitudeDelta: region.longitudeDelta,
          error: null
        }
      })
}, err => {
  console.log(err)
  alert('fetching the position failed')
}, {enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 0})
```

As per [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PositionOptions/maximumAge) :

> The PositionOptions.maximumAge property is a positive long value indicating the maximum age in milliseconds of a possible cached position that is acceptable to return. If set to 0, it means that the device cannot use a cached position and must attempt to retrieve the real current position. If set to Infinity the device must return a cached position regardless of its age.

Comment: If I keep that then my map sometimes not at all loading it takes so much time

Comment: That's the trade-off, as per your use case, you have to decide. how often you want to retrieve the real position rather using the cached one and set the maximumAge  variable accordingly. :)

Comment: If I give any value to the maximumAge property the map is not at all loading that is iam ot getting the current postion

Comment: Is your gps/location on? switch it on and try again.